# How to define a function that counts the lower cases letters until reaching a value?

Tags: python, string

Define a function countLowerFromUntil(...) which receives one string (st) and an integer value (start) as input. The string may potentially also be the empty string. This function should return how many lower case letters there are in the input string st, starting to count (and including) the start position and advancing one position at a time until reaching the end of the string or until reaching a digit (if there is such). The string may contain letters or digits. If the start value is out of the string range the function should return 0. Note: Keep in mind the string method islower() which returns true is applied to a character or a string containing only lower case letters.

For example countLowerFromUntil("ABCxAxx1aa") should return 3, because there are three lower case letters (3 "x"'s) before reaching the digit 1

As an example, the following code fragment:

```
val = countLowerFromUntil("ABCxAxx1aa",0)

print (val)
```

should produce the output:

```
3
```

so far I have this but I get an error:

```
def countLowerFromUntil(st,ch):
    s = st().strip()

    count = 1
    for i in s:
        if i.islower():
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account `start`. Start iterating from the start index. You can slice what you need. You don't need to strip (stripping spaces might invalidate `start`)

The algorithm goes like this:

- counts begin from 0
- if you encounter a digit, stop counting!
- if you encounter a lower-case character, increment your counter.
- return `count` at the end of the function

---

```
def f(string, start):
    count = 0
    for c in string[start:]:
        if c.isdigit():
            break
        elif c.islower():
            count += 1

    return count
```

```
>>> f("ABCxAxx1aa", 0)
3
```